# Conditional standard deviation? STD.S with IF not working; trying to apply to data after using AVERAGEIFS with same conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula, standard-deviation, array-formulas

*(I am working with a Spanish interface, so please forgive the code in Spanish (the ; is a , in English, PROMEDIO.SI.CONJUNTO is AVERAGEIFS, INDICE is INDEX, FILA is ROW, DESVEST.M is STD.S, SI is IF, Y is AND).*

I have look through all the threads about a "stvifs" (which Excel really should think about in the future!) and I am still unable to  apply what I've learned to my data, even though it seems exactly like what I've seen! After successfully applying the following to my data:

```
=PROMEDIO.SI.CONJUNTO(E:E;A:A; INDICE(I:I; 2+(FILA(1:1)-1));D:D; 1;F:F; "BC")
```

I automatically got my column with "BC" and their means for each participant. (I have four conditions in total.) Now I want the SD for the SAME conditions. I tried applying this code as an array formula:

```
{=DESVEST.M(SI(Y((A:A)=INDICE(I:I; 2+(FILA(1:1)-1));(D:D)=1;(F:F) ="BC");E:E))}
```

I get a #DIV/0! error. I debugged the formula, and it is giving me FALSE as a result within the STD.S, hence the error. But what I don't understand is why it's not giving me an array with all the values in the column E that comply with the given conditions! The interesting thing is that when I apply the formula normally, it gives me STD.S(E:E) correctly, so I feel that this should work! I have done something similar with other data, but there weren't multiple conditions. Please help!

Comment: The short answer is that AND (Y) doesn't work very well in an array formula so you have to replace it with a multiplication. I couldn't quite work out what the ROW (FILA) part of the formula was doing, but it's all good as I am trying (unsuccessfully) to learn Spanish.

Answer (score 1):

The formula would look something like this (in English) but not sure about ROW part and can't test it properly without some sample data:-

```
=STDEV.S(IF((A1:A10=INDEX(I1:I10, 2+ROW(1:1)-1))*(D1:D10=1)*(F1:F10 ="BC"),E1:E10))
```

Have limited it to 10 rows to make debugging easier with 'Evaluate Formula'.

This gives the stdev (sample) of the three shaded cells:-

[image]